# Git doesn't push my files

Tags: git, version-control, push

I have a Git repository on my laptop, and a server, far, far away.

I did this on the server:

```
$ cd apps
$ mkdir my_beautiful_app
$ git init --bare
```

On my laptop, I did this:

```
$ cd beautiful_app_dir
$ git remote add website my_user@11.22.33.44:apps/my_beautiful_app
$ git push website master
```

It seemed like it was transferring stuff so I thought this was working.
But actually not. On the server, in the `my_beautiful_app` directory, I have no trace of the files of the project. And now I have plenty of files and directories I didn't ask for:

On the server:

```
$ ls ~/apps/my_beautiful_app
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Well that is unexpected.
Why do I get this strange behavior? How can I get the directory on the server to sync with my local directory?

EDIT:

Ok I tried the same thing but without the `--bare` option. Here's what I got:

```
$ git push website master
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The files you're seeing on the server are the contents of what would normally be the `.git` subdirectory in your repository. You only have those because you created a bare repository - if that's not what you want, remove the `--bare` flag from `git init`.

See e.g. http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work either without the `--bare` flag. The messages are very scary  (see my edit). I'm scared.